# Promise not returning properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following function.  It calls itself repeatedly and iterates through ftp servers checking for new files. I'm trying to make it a promise so that I can `operate().then(function(newFilesObject)`, but I can't get the `.then` on operate to activate.  It does attempt to resolve it but doesn't send through. By the way, newFiles is a global variable that gets the files per server appended to it. If more code is wanted I can post or github it.

```
function operate(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if(servers[i]){
      if(i!== 0) ftp = new JSFtp(servers[i].server)
      local = servers[i].local
      remote = servers[i].remote
      localFiles = fs.readdirSync(local)
    }else{
      console.log('trying to resolve')
      console.log(newFiles)
      resolve(newFiles)
    }
    gatherFiles(remote).then(function(files){
      if(files.length>0){
        downloadNew(files).then(function(){
          console.log('Done: ' + servers[i].server.host)
          i++
          operate()
        })
      }else{
        console.log('No updates: ' + servers[i].server.host)
        i++
        operate()
      }
    })
  })
}

operate().then(function(files){
console.log('files: ' + files)
})
```

Comment: Look at the inner calls of `operate()`. Operate returns a promise but you are not doing anything with it.

Comment: That is just so I can iterate through the server again, if you understand what I'm saying. if it's over (as tested at the beginning) it resolves. What can I do with it? note: https://github.com/dkran/FloorCoveringEDI/blob/combinator/app.js

Comment: Lets put it differently: if  `if(servers[i])` is `true`, you are never calling `resolve`. Maybe you want to resolve after the promise returned by an inner `operate()` call resolves?

Comment: it does print the "trying to resolve" line though after both servers are processed. I did try to do something similar to what you're saying, but I'm not sure if I know how to return / resolve it that way

Comment: Sure, some inner call of `operate()` will go through that path. But every call to `operate()` has its own `resolve` and each of them has to call its `resolve`. I think what makes this a bit more complex is the fact that you are dealing with global variables. Avoid them if you can.

Comment: ah, I understand you now. so I'm almost returning the wrong promise, I want to return the last instead of the first.  Maybe I can put a final call to `return operate.then(...` in the else statement in the beginning

Comment: You are not returning a wrong promise, but you are never resolving (some) of them, so the code that depends on the promise (i.e. in your last lines), will never be executed.

Comment: ohhh.. interesting concept, but I'm not sure how to fix this yet. gives me ideas for some more tinkering perhaps.  If you look at the code on github you might understand why I have globals

Comment: figured it out.  since I'm recursively calling it, I have to do `resolve(operate())` and it both iterates and returns the file structure.  If you create the answer for this I'll check you off. You deserve it.

Comment: I suggest to avoid using `resolve/reject` everywhere. Extract your async task to a helper function that returns the promise, so that the looping function only uses promises, not callbacks.

Comment: I understand. I'm sort of doing an insane anti-pattern. huh? It took me a long time to get the operate() function working properly without returning a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promises in the code sample do not return as their resolvers or rejectors are not always invoked. In fact, `resolve` is only invoked when `i === 0`. According to the [Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/), promises may only be transitioned to a `fulfilled` state by invoking `resolve`. It also can only be transitioned to a `rejected` state by invoking `reject` or throwing an exception from within the executor. Therefore, reaching the end of the executor without invoking either or passing one as a callback ensures the promise remains in `pending` state indefinitely.

The goal you seek may be achieved with a little refactoring. Considering the following as your goal:

1. Sequentially through each FTP server...
2. Read a given directory for a list of files
3. Compare list of files to one stored locally to determine new ones
4. If there are new ones, download them sequentially
5. Return a list of all newly downloaded files

Data

```
var knownFTPServers = [{
  'localDirectory': 'sub/',
  'localFilepaths': ['docA.json', 'docB.json'],
  'remoteDirectory': 'remsub/',
  'remoteFilepaths': [],
  'jsftpHandle': undefined,
  'host': 'example.com'
},
{
  'localDirectory': 'root/',
  'localFilepaths': ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'],
  'remoteDirectory': 'remroot/',
  'remoteFilepaths': [],
  'jsftpHandle': undefined,
  'host': 'geocities.com'
}];
```

Logic

```
function pullNewFilesFromFTPServer(ftpServer) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var handle = new JSFtp(ftpServer);
    ftpServer.jsftpHandle = new JSFtp(ftpServer);

    // Returns a promise for reading a directory from JSFtp server
    // resolves with file list
    // rejects with FTP error
    function readdir(directory) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        handle.ls(ftpServer.remoteDirectory, function (err, res) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(res);
        });
      });
    }

    // Returns a promise for downloading a file from a remote JSFtp server
    // resolves with the filepath of the downloaded filepath
    // rejects with FTP error
    function downloadFile(path) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        handle.get(path, path, function (err) {
          if (err) return reject(err);
          resolve(path);
        });
      });
    }

    // get all remote filepaths on server
    readdir(ftpServer.remoteDirectory)

    // filter out filepaths already present locally
    .then(function (remoteFilepaths) {
      return remoteFilepaths.filter(function (path) {
        return ftpServer.localFilepaths.indexOf(path) < 0;
      });
    })

    // download new filepaths sequentially
    // reduce turns the array of new filepaths into a promise chain
    // return new filepaths after completing the promise chain
    .then(function (newFilepaths) {
      return newFilepaths.reduce(function (previousDownloadPromise, newPath) {
        return previousDownloadPromise.then(function () {
          return downloadFile(newPath);
        });
      }, Promise.resolve())
      .then(function () { return newFilepaths; });
    })

    // resolve server promise with new filepaths or reject with errors
    .then(resolve, reject);
  });
}

var allFilesDownloaded = [];
knownFTPServers.reduce(function (previousServerPromise, server) {
  return previousServerPromise.then(function (filesDownloaded) {
    allFilesDownloaded = allFilesDownloaded.concat(filesDownloaded);
    return pullNewFilesFromFTPServer(server);
  });
}, Promise.resolve([]))

.then(function () {
  console.log(allFilesDownloaded);
}, function (err) {
  console.err(err);
});
```

Though it may seem a little more complicated in some places, the actions of each function are more modular. The idea that is somewhat unintuitive is using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to turn an array of data into an array of promises executed sequentially.

Since creating a promise to download a file attempts to download the file immediately, one can't create all the promises at once if one intends to download them one at a time. Otherwise, the sequence might look a somewhat simpler.